# Transforming an optimization problem to maxmin formulation

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization, approximation-algorithms, np

Given $N=mn$ real numbers $a_i$, we seek to partition them into $n$ subsets $S_j$ ($1\le j\le n$), each containing $m$ numbers, so as to maximize $\prod_{j=1}^n \sum_{a_i\in S_j} a_i$. My questions are: (1) Can this problem be cast to a known problem? (2) Given its NP-hardness, how to design approximation algorithms with constant approximation factor?

Comment: After thinking over the problem, the transformation is impossible. Now the problem is how to solve the original problem, i.e., maximize $\prod_{j=1}^n\sum_{a_i\in S_i} a_i$

Comment: Looks like an NP-hard problem to me...

Comment: @dohmatob Thank you. Any idea on approximation algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate the problem by minimizing the range via integer linear programming.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether number $i\in N$ is assigned to group $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.  The problem is to minimize $u-\ell$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{i,j} &=1 &&\text{for all $i$}\\
\sum_i x_{i,j} &= m &&\text{for all $j$}\\
\ell \le \sum_i a_i x_{i,j} &\le u &&\text{for all $j$}
\end{align}
To obtain a formulation for the min-max or max-min problem, omit the parts involving $\ell$ or $u$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you Rob for the comment. However, the ILP formulation is still relatively intractable. I want to have structural insight on the problem. Let me pose the following two questions: (1) is the problem NP-hard, if yes, how to prove this? (2) how to design approximation algorithms?

Comment: How big are $n$ and $m$?

Comment: In the general case we do not pose any condition on $n$ or $m$. However, I am interested in the case of large $n$ and small $m$ (e.g., $4$ or $5$).

Comment: How large is large? :)  I would guess that even for fixed $m$, the problem is NP-hard, but that doesn't mean that a commercial ILP solver can't solve it quickly in practice.  Do you have sample data in mind?

Comment: The size is beyond any commercial ILP solver. Therefore we seek a poly-time approximation algorithm with hopefully constant approximation factor. I have revised the problem formulation.

Comment: Without the constraint that each subset contains $m$ numbers, the Longest Processing Time (LPT) heuristic provides a 4/3-approximation for the min-max problem.

Comment: Thank you Rob for the comment. I am aware of that line of research on number partitioning. However, the problem is not exactly the same here,which is to maximize the product-sum. Have you got an idea if we can prove any approximation ratio using algorithms in that area?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is partial.

We assume that all $a_i$ are non-negative. Put $A=\tfrac 1m \sum a_i$ and $A_j=\sum_{i\in S_j} a_i$. We want to maximize $\Pi=\prod A_j$. But by AM-GM inequality, $P^{1/m}\le \tfrac 1m \sum A_j=A$  and the equality holds iff each $A_j$ equals $A$.

Even when $m=2$ and all $a_i$ are positive integers the problem to check whether the equality can hold is a [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Variants_and_generalizations) of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), and at the first reference is stated that it is $NP$-hard (but without a citation). So this should be a known problem and there can be already developed heuristic and approximation algorithms for it.

I guess that a heuristics can be based on some balancing idea, which looks promising when there are no big gaps between $a_i$’s.

For instance, I can propose the following algorithm to find an initial feasible partition. Assign $m$ piles, order $a_i$ in a non-increasing order, and then split this sequence of $a_i$’s into bags $B_1,\dots, B_n$ each containing $m$ consecutive $a_i$’s. An each step we pick a next bag and distribute its $a_i$’s into the piles, one number to each pile, trying to make the vector of  the sums of elements of the piles more balanced (a measure of a balancedness of a vector $x=(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ can be a norm (for instance, $\ell_2$ or $\ell_\infty$) of a vector $x-\left(\frac 1m \sum x_i\right) (1,1,\dots,1)$). I guess this should be done as follows: put the biggest element of the bag to the pile with the smallest sum, the second biggest element of the bag to the second smallest sum, and so forth.

The obtained feasible partition (or even a random one) can be further iterative balanced by local search. Namely, given sets $S_1,\dots S_m$ and a small constant $b\ge 1$ (maybe even $b=1$ will provide a good approximation) we check all subsets $C_i$ of size $b$ in each of $S_j$ (so there are  ${n\choose b}^m$ possibilities to consider in total). For each of the possibilities we consider a union $C$ of $C_i$ and try to redistribute $C$ between $S_j$ trying to make the sequence of their sums more balanced. In particular, when $b=1$ and $m=2$, we look for indices $i_1\in S_1$ and $i_2\in S_2$ such that when we swap $i_1$ and $i_2$ between $S_1$ and $S_2$, the difference $|A_1-A_2|$ will decrease.

Comment: Thank you Alex for the valuable comments. For the case $m=2$, I can show that the problem is already NP-hard by relating it to the number partitioning problem. Your idea actually coincides with the heuristics there, my question is on how to prove any approximation results using such idea.

Comment: @lchen I guess we can obtain approximation results if there are some restrictions on $a_i$’s, providing the proposed heuristics gives the values of $A_i$’s  close to $A$.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Do we really need that. My feeling is that the heuristic gives quite good approximations, but fail to derive any bound.